# Keep getting an error when trying to submit an Inbound Shipment via Netsuite Restlet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I keep getting the following error when trying to create a new Inbound Shipment record (new in Netsuite).

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"Please enter value(s) for: Item","stack":["anonymous(N/recordService)","<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:132)","<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:99)","doPost(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:34)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"USER_ERROR","details":"Please enter value(s) for: Item","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["anonymous(N/recordService)","<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:132)","<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:99)","doPost(/SuiteScripts/KK_Sandbox_Scripts_SD/RestLets/InboundShipment.js:34)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false}
```

Here is the code I have to set the record. I have verified that the sublist id is "items" and the fieldId is "itemid", but when I try to add the line, I get the above error.

```
function doPost(restletBody){
log.debug('Called from POST', restletBody);

var success = [],
errors = [];

restletBody.data.forEach(function(e) 
{
    try 
    {
        log.debug('Called from POST', e.id);

        //Create a new record
        var rec =
            r.create({
                type: "inboundshipment",
                isDynamic: true,
                defaultValues: null
            }).setValue({
                fieldId: "externalid",
                value: e.id,
                ignoreFieldChange: false
            });

        var i = 1;

    e.lineitems.items.forEach(function(item)
        {
            log.debug("Inside Line Items", item.itemid + " " + item.purchaseorder);


            rec.selectNewLine({sublistId:"items"});

            var field = rec.getSublistFields({
                sublistId: 'items'
            });

            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: "items",
                fieldId: "purchaseorder",
                value: item.purchaseorder,
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });

            rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: "items",
                fieldId: "itemid",
                value: item.itemid,
                ignoreFieldChange: true
            });
            log.debug("Inside Line Items", "ITEM Added " + item.itemid );

            rec.commitLine({sublistId:"items"});
            log.debug("Inside Line Items", "Line Committed" );

            ++i;
        });

        rec.save();
    }
    catch(err) 
    {
        var msg = '';
        log.debug("There was an error", err);
    }
})
return "";
```

}

I have tried changing the itemid to shipmentitem and id, and it doesn't work. Before, I was getting an error for PO, too, and it was because the name was wrong, but I fixed that (I believe) for the item.

One thing that might be affecting it (not sure) is that the PO list filters the item list. once the user selects the PO in the UI, it will filter the item list to only items on that PO. I have double-checked that the item I am trying to submit belongs to the PO I am trying to submit, but still receiving an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [NetSuite Record Browser](https://debugger.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/script/record/inboundshipment.html), the field should be 'shipmentitem'.

```
rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: "items",
    fieldId: "shipmentitem",
    value: item.itemid,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});
```

EDIT: Updated to reflect that the fieldname should be 'shipmentitem' as @shawleigh17 discovered so future users find the correct answer.

Comment: I tried this, but still have the same issue. When I print out the fields for the sublist 'items' I get the following  `["fulfillable","quantityexpected","pocurrency","quantityremaining","itemid","quantityreceived","purchaseorder","id","shipmentitemamount","vendorid","shipmentitem","sequencenumber","fxrate","porate","shipmentitemdescription","povendor","unit","itemtype","receivinglocation","quantitybilled","currencyprecision","incoterm","expectedrate","quantityexpectedorig","unitrate"]`

Comment: Looking at the record browser, it looks like shipmentitem is also required. When I add one manually and save, the shipmentitem is different than the item, and I can't select it in the ui (i am looking at it via a record browser tool in chrome). If I try to set that value, I am typically told that it is an invalid value. I'm not sure if this is a kind of key that gets added, or if I should be setting it myself. The record browser says it is a select, but it is not in the UI, so I am not sure what the values are.

Comment: It's because I am setting the wrong field. It should be shipmentitem. Thank you for your help! You got me on the right track.

Comment: @shawleigh17 - I tried shipmentitem and I'm getting an Invalid Field Value error. I saw on your comments that you've experienced this as well. As when I'm trying to add the item manually, the value on the shipmentitem is different that the item than I added. How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

all you need is a PO line unique Id (line field id: `lineuniquekey`) of each from original PO/POs and transaction Id. This id you will set for shipmentitem sublist field of Inbound Shipment record.

```
                objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'items',
                    fieldId: 'purchaseorder',
                    value: objParam.purchaseOrderId,
                    forceSyncSourcing: true
                });
                objRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'items',
                    fieldId: 'shipmentitem',
                    value: objParam.lineUniqueIdFromPO,
                    forceSyncSourcing: true
                });
```

and of course, do not forget to set quantity for `quantityexpected`